# GoTo when something happens

Tags: excel, vba

I want to show a mensage and end the Macro when my variable = 10 for example, tried this and didnt worked.

```
Sub test()

Dim v1 as Integer   

On v1 = 10 GoTo Erro1

If Activecell.Value > 10 then

    v1 = 10

End If

.
.
.

Exit Sub

Error1:

Msgbox("Erro")

End Sub
```

Comment: In general, that's very bad practice when coding.  What are you actually trying to do?  Provide sample data of before the macro, and what you want the result to be, along with the code you've written.

Comment: It should be 'If' not 'on'.  Plus your goto will never execute with the code you have provided because v1 will always be 0 when you get to the If statement.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Goto` makes spaghetti code and is always much less desirable than alternatives like calling a function, looping, implementing if blocks, etc.

Instead:

```
Sub test()

  Dim v1 as Integer

  If Activecell.Value > 10 then
    If v1 = 10 Then
       msgbox "Erro"
       Exit Sub
    End If
  End If

End Sub
```